# Parameters validation in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I am trying to validate parameters that I want to output.

I have a title in a one row where are 3 data blocks.

Title: "Name: John Smith, Country: Italy, Job: CEO"

Data comes from db and I need a validation so if any data lock has null then it doesn't appear in the title. For example if job is missing, then title will be "Name: John Smith, Country: Italy"

Hao can I do this?

Comment: What exactly is the markup? This is commonly done with v-if if these are different elements.

Comment: If statement is escaping the whole validation chain once if statement is true. So if doesn't work here. John Smith, Italy and CEO are the parameters here which should be validated if they aren't nulls

Comment: I mean that normally it's solved as `<span v-if="name">Name: {name}</span>`. If it's supposed to be a single string with commas then concatenate it with conditions. This is regular JS task that is not specific to Vue.

Answer (score 0):

`v-if` is commonly used for this:

```
<span v-if="user.name">Name: {user.name}</span>
...
```

The use of inline elements allows to render it as a single line.

If it's necessary to concatenate fields with commas and a line doesn't need additional markup, it can be conditionally concatenated and likely be computed property:

```
return [
  user.name && `Name: ${user.name}`,
  ...
].filter(Boolean).join(', ');
```